# added button in table by jquery is not work can you tell me what is problem?

Tags: jquery, django, templates, bootstrap-modal

problom is that button in table added by jquery is not work

[image]

basic output of button

```
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning float-right comment_delete_button" id="{{comment.pk}}">delete</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info float-right comment_edit_button" id="{{comment.pk}}">edit</button>
```

added button

```
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning float-right comment_delete_button" id="<%= comment_id %>">delete</button>
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info float-right comment_edit_button" id="<%= comment_id %>">edit</button>
```

I looked it up using f12 and it did not differ. But why is the event listener not working?

```
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'update_comment_ajax/'+id,
          data: {
              id:id,
              title:title,
              file_name:file_name,
              text:text,
              csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
          },
            success: function(result) {
                alert('comment update complete ');
            }
        });
    });


    $(".comment_delete_button").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        alert('삭제 id : ' + id);
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'delete_comment_ajax/'+id,
          data: {
              csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
          },
            success: function(result) {
                $("#comment_table_"+id ).remove();
                alert('comment 삭제 complete ');
            }
        });
    });
```

thanks for let me know how to fix it ~!

Answer (score 1):

Two of your buttons have the same Ids. Both the edit and delete buttons have the id of `{{comment.pk}}` .
Change them to `{{comment.pk}}_delete` and `{{comment.pk}}_edit`. 
When you have two elements with the same ids, jQuery wouldn't work.